# How to bulk rename files to remove an extraneous space from before the extension

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find, rename

I have a bunch of files who's filename follows the pattern 'filename.ext'. eg:

```
filename .ext
```

I would like to rename all of these to remove the space before the .ext. eg:

```
filename.ext
```

I can find them all using

```
find * -type f -name'* .*'
```

but how can I then rename all these files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a file named "renamethis.sh".  Its contents should be:

```
#!/bin/bash
mv "$1" "$(echo $1 | sed 's/ \././')"
```

Set the executable bit: `chmod a+x renamethis.sh`.  Then, run something like:

`find /path/to/dir -name '* .*' -type f -print0 | xargs -0L 1 /path/to/renamethis.sh`

YMMV, no warranty express or implied, etc.

FWIW, the spaces are what makes this strange; as long as you don't have other oddball characters in the files names, you're good to go with this approach.  If you do, you may want to consider something like a scandir/readdir loop in Perl or PHP, but the above script is the first thing that came to mind.

Comment: Instead of using a custom script I suggest you to use the command `rename` which comes on every major distro. Check it's man page.

Comment: For "rename" to work, you'd have to have a complete list of all the extensions.  So something like: `for ext in $(find /path/to/dir -name '* .*' -type f | sed 's/.* \.//;s/ .*//'); do rename " .$ext" .$ext /path/to/dir/*\ .$ext; done`.  Without testing, though, not sure if `rename` is going to play nice with that glob, and it seems like a roundabout way to use a specific tool, so I think I still prefer my approach in circumstances where there's more than one extension that needs to be changed.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your concerns about rename. It works exactly as your sed command.

Comment: for exaple given this tree structure and several files with "any number of spaces prior to a dot extension" as follows:

    `mkdir -p a/deep/tree`
    `touch a/'foo .ext' a/deep/'bar  .otherext' a/deep/tree/'x .foo'`

You can find and rename all of them with rename:

     `find a/ -name '* .*' -exec rename -v 's/ *\././' '{}' \;'`

resulting in:

 `a/deep/tree/x .foo renamed as a/deep/tree/x.foo`
 `a/deep/bar  .otherext renamed as a/deep/bar.otherext`
 `a/foo .ext renamed as a/foo.ext`

Comment: @hmontoliu I see what you did there.  Neat approach!  :)

Comment: @hmontoliu 's suggestion `find <DIR>/ -name '* .*' -exec rename -v 's/ *\././' '{}' \;` (without the last single quote mark) does the job very neatly but I wonder why `find . -name '* .*' -exec rename -v 's/ *\././' '{}' \;`  doesn't work?..

Answer (score 1):

This should do it for you.

```
#!/bin/bash

OLDIFS=${IFS}
IFS=$'\n'

for file in `find * -type f -name '* .*'`; do
 _ext=`echo ${file} | cut -d '.' -f 2-`
 _filename=`echo ${file} | cut -d ' ' -f 1`
 mv "${file}" ${_filename}.${_ext}
done

IFS=${OLDIFS}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However the cut command didn't find the extension correctly when there were other spaces or dots in the filename. But thanks for responding.

Comment: No problem, glad you found a solution though. His is definitely more elegant than mine.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you've already solved your immediate problem, but in the future you might want to consider using `mmv`.

Comment: This is _perfect_

Answer (score 1):

In one line:

```
find -depth -name '* .*' -print0 |
perl -wn0e '$orig = $_; s/\s+\././g; rename($orig, $_) or warn "$orig: $!\n"'
```

Highlights:

- no problem with quoting spaces in filenames
- no problem with filenames starting with a dash
- fast: only two processes started in parallel
- handles directories correctly